# How to set pts time format when using ffmpeg filter to add timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I want to add timestamp of current played time to a video, so I use this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf: 
       text='timestamp: %{pts \: hms}': x=5: y=5: fontsize=16:
       fontcolor=yellow@0.9: box=1: boxcolor=blue@0.6" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -map 0 output.mkv
```

This comes out that the timestamp was in hh:mm:ss:mm format, but I want it in hh:mm:ss format. So how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
text='timestamp \: %{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%H\\\:%M\\\:%S}'
```

Comment: It went wrong: `[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7fe6e840fd40] Could not load font "%M\": cannot open resource` and `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fe6e8708020] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile ***'`

Comment: I'm on Windows. You probably are using the bash shell. You can try skipping the slashes between H M and S.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! On macOS use this: `text='timestamp \: %{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%H %M %S}'`, It seems that `\:` between H M and S is not allowed. So the ":" has not escaped. I'm wondering how to escape ":". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WayneChen 
Fedora Linux fish I used `"...:text=%{pts\\\:hms}"` as an example for escaping parameters.  I already had to escape single quote character using this: `set fileE (echo "$file" | sed 's|\'|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|')`, so I would say keep adding slashes carefully until it works interpreted as a literal and not a filter or function parameter/argument separator.

Answer (score 6):

### Do

In order to draw `Timestamp: 01:25.`, you should specify this one to (feed) `ffmpeg`:

```
drawtext = text = 'Timestamp\: %{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\:%S}.'
```

### Don't

If you specify this one to (feed) `ffmpeg`:

```
drawtext = text = '%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\:%S}'
```

, it gives `Unterminated %{} near '{pts:gmtime:0:%M\'` error.

### But in `bash`

But if you're using `bash`-like shell and a weak quote, `"......"`, to feed it,

1. `\\` is escaped to `\`, and
2. `\:` is not escaped but remains without any changes because `\:` is not an escape sequence.

So it should be:

```
-filter_complex "drawtext = text = '%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\\\:%S}'"
```

i.e. `bash`'s `"\\\\\:"` for `ffmpeg`'s `\\\:` for getting a single character `:` displayed.

### Note that

If you only want to apply one or more filters to one video stream (e.g, `drawtext`), you can use `-vf` instead of using `--filter_complex`. The latter is reserved for applying filters on multiple streams.